# Float text around image

Tags: html, css

I need help creating a text container floating around the price tag like seen on this picture :

[image]

Here is what I've tried so far:

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kzmndzj4)**

HTML :

```
<div class="product">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    <div class="pricetag">
    999 €
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```css
.product
{
    width: 258px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25px;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
}

.pricetag
{
    height: 54px;
    width: 115px;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ES3wymx.png') no-repeat;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I want the price tag be always on a certain position (so it's on the same position for each product) and the text floating around like on the picture I posted.

Comment: can you do fiddle with your tried code?

Comment: Please show us some of your code, or what you've tried so far if you have anything. It's hard to know exactly where you're at, and exactly what help you're asking for.

Comment: I edited quite a bit too. Your question should now be reopened. Wait for other users attention

Comment: You should closed your duplicated question and wait for this one to reopen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that works only if you have fixed height divs (here `.product`) :

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wq1rtuu5/)**

You will have to put your `.pricetag` div before the text. Then, the main trick is to use a spacer floated right with a width of 0 :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="pricetagspacer"></div>
    <div class="pricetag">
        999 €
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```css
.pricetag
{
    height: 54px;
    width: 115px;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ES3wymx.png') no-repeat;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    clear: right; /* to be positioned under the spacer */
    position: relative; 
    right: -24px; /* to go a bit offside */
    margin-left: -24px; /* corrected margin because of the previous line */
}
.pricetagspacer {
    height: 100%; /* to space the whole height */
    width: 0; /* so we don't have more "padding" on the right of .product */
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: -65px; /* to eventually position correctly the .pricetag */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply a float on your image, or div that you want to have on the right hand side.

```
div {float:right;}
```

Comment: I don't think it should be spoon fed

Comment: There's a trick to use, not just float right do that and I'm not going to answer as OP has not shown his effort...

Comment: @C-linkNepal OP has now edited his post. I also have a solution to provide. It would be great to reopen this question

Answer (score 0):

Tip

sub

```
position:absolute; z-index:2;
```

main

```
position:relative; z-index:1;
```